# Linq conditional where not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

The following is not producing a where clause in SQL.

The `search.Where` parts are being executed when I debug but do not appear when I look in SQL profiler.

```
using (var db = new CERTContext())
{
    var search = db.Project.Include("ValueStream").Include("Function").AsQueryable();
    if (!lookForDate)
    {
        search.Where(p => p.ProjectName.Contains(searchText) ||
                          p.ProjectDescription.Contains(searchText) ||
                          p.EquipmentName.Contains(searchText) ||
                          p.ValueStream.Description.Contains(searchText) || 
                          p.ValueStream.Description.Contains(searchText) ||
                          p.TrackingId.Contains(searchText) ||
                          p.ENumber.Contains(searchText) ||
                          p.ShamrockNumber.Contains(searchText));

        //.Take(10)
        //.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectID);
        //.ToList();
    }
    else
    {// Search on date
        search.Where(p =>
        (System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.StartDate) == searchDate));
        //.Take(10)
        //.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectID);
        //.ToList();
    }                              
    if (showDeleted != true)
    {
        search.Where(p => p.Deleted == false);
    }
    pList = search.Take(10).OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectID).ToList();

}// using (var db = new CERTContext())
```

This is what I get.
It has the select top 10, the orderby and the joins but no where.

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[ProjectID] AS [ProjectID], 
[Limit1].[FunctionId] AS [FunctionId], 
[Limit1].[ValueStreamId] AS [ValueStreamId], 
[Limit1].[TrackingId] AS [TrackingId], 
[Limit1].[VersionNo] AS [VersionNo], 
[Limit1].[VersionDate] AS [VersionDate], 
[Limit1].[ProjectName] AS [ProjectName], 
[Limit1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Limit1].[Closed] AS [Closed], 
[Limit1].[ProjectLead] AS [ProjectLead], 
[Limit1].[ProjectDescription] AS [ProjectDescription], 
[Limit1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
[Limit1].[CurrentPhase] AS [CurrentPhase], 
[Limit1].[ENumber] AS [ENumber], 
[Limit1].[ShamrockNumber] AS [ShamrockNumber], 
[Limit1].[EquipmentName] AS [EquipmentName], 
[Limit1].[ConceptExpectedEndDate] AS [ConceptExpectedEndDate], 
[Limit1].[PlanningExpectedEndDate] AS [PlanningExpectedEndDate], 
[Limit1].[DesignExpectedEndDate] AS [DesignExpectedEndDate], 
[Limit1].[InstallExpectedEndDate] AS [InstallExpectedEndDate], 
[Limit1].[DeployExpectedEndDate] AS [DeployExpectedEndDate], 
[Limit1].[ConceptActualEndDate] AS [ConceptActualEndDate], 
[Limit1].[PlanningActualEndDate] AS [PlanningActualEndDate], 
[Limit1].[DesignActualEndDate] AS [DesignActualEndDate], 
[Limit1].[InstallActualEndDate] AS [InstallActualEndDate], 
[Limit1].[DeployActualEndDate] AS [DeployActualEndDate], 
[Limit1].[ScalingQ1Text] AS [ScalingQ1Text], 
[Limit1].[ScalingQ2Text] AS [ScalingQ2Text], 
[Limit1].[ScalingQ3Text] AS [ScalingQ3Text], 
[Limit1].[ScalingQ1Answer] AS [ScalingQ1Answer], 
[Limit1].[ScalingQ2Answer] AS [ScalingQ2Answer], 
[Limit1].[ScalingQ3Answer] AS [ScalingQ3Answer], 
[Limit1].[ScalingNotes] AS [ScalingNotes], 
[Limit1].[CreateUserName] AS [CreateUserName], 
[Limit1].[LastUserName] AS [LastUserName], 
[Limit1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Limit1].[EditedDate] AS [EditedDate], 
[Extent2].[ValueStreamId] AS [ValueStreamId1], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent3].[FunctionID] AS [FunctionId1], 
[Extent3].[Description] AS [Description1]
FROM    (SELECT TOP (10) [c].[ProjectID] AS [ProjectID], [c].[FunctionId] AS [FunctionId], [c].[ValueStreamId] AS [ValueStreamId], [c].[TrackingId] AS [TrackingId], [c].[VersionNo] AS [VersionNo], [c].[VersionDate] AS [VersionDate], [c].[ProjectName] AS [ProjectName], [c].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], [c].[Closed] AS [Closed], [c].[ProjectLead] AS [ProjectLead], [c].[ProjectDescription] AS [ProjectDescription], [c].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [c].[CurrentPhase] AS [CurrentPhase], [c].[ENumber] AS [ENumber], [c].[ShamrockNumber] AS [ShamrockNumber], [c].[EquipmentName] AS [EquipmentName], [c].[ConceptExpectedEndDate] AS [ConceptExpectedEndDate], [c].[PlanningExpectedEndDate] AS [PlanningExpectedEndDate], [c].[DesignExpectedEndDate] AS [DesignExpectedEndDate], [c].[InstallExpectedEndDate] AS [InstallExpectedEndDate], [c].[DeployExpectedEndDate] AS [DeployExpectedEndDate], [c].[ConceptActualEndDate] AS [ConceptActualEndDate], [c].[PlanningActualEndDate] AS [PlanningActualEndDate], [c].[DesignActualEndDate] AS [DesignActualEndDate], [c].[InstallActualEndDate] AS [InstallActualEndDate], [c].[DeployActualEndDate] AS [DeployActualEndDate], [c].[ScalingQ1Text] AS [ScalingQ1Text], [c].[ScalingQ2Text] AS [ScalingQ2Text], [c].[ScalingQ3Text] AS [ScalingQ3Text], [c].[ScalingQ1Answer] AS [ScalingQ1Answer], [c].[ScalingQ2Answer] AS [ScalingQ2Answer], [c].[ScalingQ3Answer] AS [ScalingQ3Answer], [c].[ScalingNotes] AS [ScalingNotes], [c].[CreateUserName] AS [CreateUserName], [c].[LastUserName] AS [LastUserName], [c].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [c].[EditedDate] AS [EditedDate]
    FROM [dbo].[Projects] AS [c] ) AS [Limit1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ValueStreams] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[ValueStreamId] = [Extent2].[ValueStreamId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Functions] AS [Extent3] ON [Limit1].[FunctionId] = [Extent3].[FunctionID]
ORDER BY [Limit1].[ProjectID] DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just calling `Where` doesn't change anything about the query you call it on. Instead, it returns a *new* query... which you're currently ignoring. You want:

```
search = search.Where(/* code as before */);
```

EDIT: You then need to also change the declaration to:

```
IQueryable<Project> search = db.Project.(code as before)
```

I'd hoped that with the `AsQueryable()`, that wouldn't be required - but apparently it is.

Comment: When I try search = search.Where(p => p.Deleted == false);

Comment: I get: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<DFxCERT.Models.Project>' to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<DFxCERT.Models.Project>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\eotuathaigh\Documents\SourceCode\BSCI\DFxCERT\DFxCERT\Services\ProjectServices.cs 286 38 DFxCERT

Comment: @Eamon: Okay, so you need to change your variable declaration. I'll edit that into my post.

Comment: Sorry Jon I must have taken the asQueryable off at somestage as this is working also.  var search = db.Project.Include("ValueStream").Include("Function").AsQueryable();

Comment: @Eamon: Right, that's what I'd have expected. (I deliberately checked for `AsQueryable` when writing my first answer, just in case...)

Answer (score 4):

Put the result search.Where back to search like this :

```
search = search.Where( // same with your code
```

Answer (score 0):

The results you got back from the query was lost. You need to assign it back to the search variable.